# Flash upload, selecting file window going back side of browser window

Tags: flash, firefox, file-upload, yui

In our website, After clicking upload button (using flash plugin), selecting file window going back side of browser window.

This issue comes only firefox (tested 32, 31, 30 & 29) with latest flash plugin i.e shockwave 15.0.0.152. but It is working fine with all other major browsers (IE8+, Safari & Chrome).

We are using YUI3.4.1 uploader and the same issue exist in YUI2 uploader. This is serious issue for website who were developed using YUI2 &  < YUI3.4.1. I think, this issue may come with other JS frameworks who using upload with flash plugin.

Unfortunately, I can not give a URL for the issue because our website requires authentication to go to that specific page. Any suggestion for fixing this issue in application side?

## Updated: (16/09/2014)

Below is the link for reproducing the issue in FF >= 32.0 with flash plugin i.e shockwave 15.0.0.152.

```
Demo URL: http://jsfiddle.net/66fu172w/
```

Answer (score 0):

By changing "wmode" to "window" will fix the problem. I got this information from bugzilla forum.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1066951

Anyway, making "wmode=window" will create performance related issues as per adobe doc. Need to know the issues in screen after changing this. will post here if any problem comes.

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html

## Update on 26/09/2014

We have temporarily fixed this issue by calling the another SWF silently with wmode="window" in page load.